# How to terminate a thread from threadpoolexecutor that import another python file?

Tags: python, multithreading

The code defines a function that import another file using importlib. And I want to import multiple files using for loops and making all imports as threads, but I came into the problem of killing those threads.

Here's my main file:

```
from concurrent import futures
import importlib
thread_pool_executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
def flexable_import(file):
    importlib.import_module(file)
file_list = ["file1","file2","file3"]
pool_list = []
for filename in file_list:
    pool_list.append(thread_pool_executor.submit(flexable_import,filename))
for i in range(len(pool_list)):
    #I want some code that can alternate the self.terminate in a class attribute from another file in another thread
```

Here's an example of a imported file in a thread:

```
import time
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.terminate = False #flag variable
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #some operation
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.terminate:
                return

a = SomeClass()
```

I wonder if there's a way to change a class attribute from another thread that imports another file, or if there's another way to staight up kill a future object. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your design.  Define your interface so that every add-in module has a function with a known name.  Consider:

```
import time
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminate = False #flag variable
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #some operation
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.terminate:
                return

def execute():
    return SomeClass()
```

Now you can do:

```
addins = []
def flexable_import(file):
    mod = importlib.import_module(file)
    addins.append( mod.execute() )

def stop_it():
    for o in addins:
        o.terminate = True
```